# excel Проверка Данных исчезли все треугольники

Tags: excel, выпадающий-список

Не пойму что я н[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ажал, но у меня куда-то **исчезли стрелочки посредством которых отображается раскрывающийся Список** - Как вернуть выпадающие списки?

Предварительно я всё сделал правильно = всё работало.
(Выполнил обычным путём: вкладка ДАННЫЕ > Проверка данных > и для каждой колонки выбирал Список из предыдущей страницы = всё сделал, всё работало, но через некоторое время исчезло = при нажатии на эти ячейки кнопка выпадающего списка НЕ отображается)

возможно исчезло после того как я пробовал в Excel (у меня на Macbook Air установлен Windows + MS Office) сочетание клавиш ctrl+;  ctrl+shift+; в instagram увидел как один добрый пользователь предложил использование этих сочетаний чтобы в ячейках отобразить текущую дату и/или текущую дату и время

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иногда требуется что-то сделать на листе, но расположенные на нем объекты мешают. Например: за графиком спрятаны вычисления и данные для него; кнопка мешает настроить форматирование... Смещать в сторону, переносить на другой лист или удалять объект - лишние, неудобные действия.

Но выход есть - в Excel встроена возможность временно скрывать/отображать объекты - комбинация клавиш **Ctrl+6**.

"Стрелочки", посредством которых отображается раскрывающийся список - это тоже объекты.

Жмем волшебное сочетание - и душевное спокойствие возвращается )

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное разъяснение.
нажал ctrl+6 и стрелочки появились

Ваш ответ был очень полезен для меня - его нужно разместить на этом сайте так чтобы такие пользователи как я могли прочитать и воспользоваться вашим четким ответом, который мне очень помог.